# MOSS Error Uploading File to Library and Custom Meta Data Not Being Updated

Tags: upload, moss, metadata

MOSS 2007 SP2 64 bit. Multi-server install.

How do I figure out the where to find the document library upload error I am getting?

I have document library with a custom workflow attached that will have a PDF document OCR'd during the upload. This library has some custom meta data fields from a content type that are exposed during the upload. As part of the workflow it OCR's the PDF doc and puts it back into the library and keeps it at version 1. During the upload I am getting an error for the PDF documents but it is uploading the document and the meta data fields are not getting updated with the user input. Below is the wonderful error message I get back. I have tried looking at the logs and I am not seeing anything pertaining to this error.

---

Go back to site
Error

The file 0746850076 Workers Compensation/a.pdf has been modified by DOMAIN\user on 14 Oct 2009 11:05:44 -0400.

### Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the current user has proper rights and that you're not having an access collision with another user.  Smells like a concurrency issue.  Ensuring that you have proper locking in place should eliminate your woes

Answer (score 0):

You probably is running into a concurrency issue; this message occurs when you do update some metadata and that document already has been modified by someone else (sometimes even you).

Before changing your metadata, try to reload your SPLIstItem/SPFile object to reflect your most actual metadata values.

Comment: Is this something that needs to be added to the workflow? Also, the error doesn't always occur. The only time it consistantly happens is when all metadata fields are filled in.

Comment: "doesn't always occur" is probably concurrency related